# counting selected items in a list box

Tags: vb.net, listbox

How do you count the amount of values in a list box that are selected, rather than all of those within the list box?

I need to get the number and then make it a string. Once i have the number i can change this easily to a string

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices.Length

Answer (score 2):

yourlistbox.SelectedItems.Count

Comment: There is only SelectedItem or Items, Items being plural but not just those that are selected, and SelectedItem just been one item?

Comment: if your're talking about System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox you might need iterate over the items and count the ones that are selected

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the items in the listbox like so:

```
    For Each item As ListItem In MyListBox.Items
        If item.Selected Then
           'Do something               
        End If
    Next
```