# How to return the number of checked items in a ListView in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listview, listviewitem

I need the count number of checked items in a ListView. So far, I tried this approaches:

```
Debug.Print ListView1.ListItems.Item(ListView1.ListItems.Count).Checked //outputs "false"
Debug.Print ListView1.ListItems(ListView1.ListItems.Count).Checked //outputs "false"
Debug.Print ListView1.ListItems.Count //outputs 13, because the LV contains 13 items
```

Is there a possibility to return the number of `checked` items in a listview without loop over the listview.

Comment: Possible duplicate, check answers at link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014493/counting-selected-items-in-a-list-box

Comment: No, you need to loop each item & count manually.

Comment: @ShaiRado Sorry but I'm speaking about `ListView` not `ListBox`! In ListViews you don't have the method `GetSelectedIndices`. And as Alex already said. I have the possibility to loop over the listview, but I'm looking for a solution without loop :) if there is one, of course.

Comment: @ShaiRado - yuro wants `VBA` not `VB.net` ...

Comment: Nothing better than looping and counting the selected. Or make a library to do it and share it with us :)

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP wants a non-looping approach - here it is for the sake of completeness. Happy to vote for an answer with a neater non-loopy approach!

Iterate the `ListItems` collection and count the items where the `Selected` property is `True`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListView1
        .ListItems.Add 1, "Hughie", "Hughie"
        .ListItems.Add 2, "Dewey", "Dewey"
        .ListItems.Add 3, "Louis", "Louis"
        .View = lvwList
        .MultiSelect = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox GetSelectedCount(Me.ListView1)
End Sub

Function GetSelectedCount(lvw As ListView) As Long
    Dim lngSelectedCounter As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    For lngCounter = 1 To lvw.ListItems.Count
        If lvw.ListItems(lngCounter).Selected Then
            lngSelectedCounter = lngSelectedCounter + 1
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    GetSelectedCount = lngSelectedCounter
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this approach, but I'm looking for a solution without loop! :) Nevertheless I give you an up vote!